# Gulp call sub modules

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-shell, gulp-folders

There is a parent folder (gulp module) which has some child folders (gulp modules too). I want to run the default gulp task of each child through the gulpfile of the parent.

My approach was to iterate through the folders by using `gulp-folders` and run a `gulp` through `gulp-shell` by setting the current work directory to the corresponding child.

```
var tOptions = {};
[...]

gulp.task('setup-modules', folders('./', function(folder){
    tOptions.cwd = folder;
    gulp.start('setup-module');
    return gulp.src('', {read: false});
}));

gulp.task('setup-module', shell.task([
    'gulp'
], tOptions));
```

It seems that just one instance of the task `setup-module` gets started. What do I need to change to get several instances (for each child folder) of the task running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `gulp-shell` you can use [`gulp-chug`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-chug) and pass a glob to `gulp.src()` to access your child gulpfiles eliminating the need to iterate over each subdirectory. You can even [specify which tasks you would like to run](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-chug#tasks) if you want to run any task(s) other than `default`.

Additionally, `gulp-chug` will do everything so there's no need to depend on more than just that one package accomplish what you're looking to do.

[One of the examples from the `gulp-chug` docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-chug#run-external-gulpfiles) goes over almost the exact scenario you're discussing.

#### gulpfile.js (parent)

```
// This example was taken from the gulp-chug docs

var gulp = require( 'gulp' );
var chug = require( 'gulp-chug' );

gulp.task( 'default', function () {

    // Find and run all gulpfiles under all subdirectories 
    gulp.src( './**/gulpfile.js' )
        .pipe( chug() )
} );
```

Comment: Thank you, actually I was looking for something like `gulp-chug`. Just needed to change the wildcard (example parent called itself recursively).

Comment: I've recognized that the `gulp.src` found all current 29 modules, but `chug` just executes about 16 of them. There is no error, just some node warnings when starting the 11th gulp task (`(node) warning: possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 SIGINT listeners added. Use
 emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit.`)  Any ideas why it stops after 16 modules? (I used the example, but replaced the string `'./**/gulpfile.js'` by `'./*/gulpfile.js'`).